# How to downcase all char and uppercase only the first characters via js?

Tags: javascript, regex

Now I have this regex:
`tSzoveg = tSzoveg.replace(/\b[A-Z]{2,}\b/,'');`

It is almost that I want. I want to convert this: `THIS IS MINE, NOT YOURS.` to this: `This is mine, not yours.`

How can I convert it to a normal sentence?

Comment: Not quite a duplicate: That question asks to leave the remaining characters alone; this question asks to downcase the remaining characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `toLowerCase()` and then modify the first letter:

```
var str = "THIS IS MINE, NOT YOURS."
str.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + str.slice(1).toLowerCase();
```

Comment: It's good, but it lowercase all characters. so the final output: `this is mine, not yours` and not `This is..`

Answer (score 4):

```
function capitalize(string)
{
    return string.toUpperCase().charAt(0) + string.toLowerCase().slice(1);
}
```

Comment: Looks like vice versa...